# unknown value linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

my program supposed to print 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
but it print
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 245858 558254
and i cant find the problem

create_list is a fucnction that return a pointer to a list_value "linked list"
create_list t calls for insertion function to add a new value in the head of the linked list.
affiche is a function that print the data "integer"

here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct liste_value
    {
        int d;
        struct liste_value *next;
    };typedef struct liste_value LISTE_VALUE;



void insertion(LISTE_VALUE **first,int a)
{
    LISTE_VALUE *p;
    p=(LISTE_VALUE*)malloc(sizeof(LISTE_VALUE));
    p->d=a;
    p->next=*first;
    *first=p;

}


LISTE_VALUE* create_list()
{   int i;
    LISTE_VALUE* first;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        insertion(&first,i);

    }
    return(first);
}

void affiche(LISTE_VALUE *first)
{   LISTE_VALUE *p=first;
    while(p)
    {
        printf("data = %d\n",p->d);
        p=p->next;
    }
}

void main()
{

    LISTE_VALUE *E;
    E=create_list();
    affiche(E);

}
```

Comment: Why not use the debugger?

Comment: And why not just tag questions properly? That has nothing to do with C++

Comment: try `LISTE_VALUE* first=NULL;`

Comment: and include <stdlib.h>

Comment: @EdHeal i already did

Comment: @Manu343726 i think who knows c++ knows C basics so he can help me

Comment: Thats true, but tags are for questions topics, not to pay attention of answerers. Think that when you post a question on this site, is not only for you, its for everybody who search for help. **And I don't wan't people searching for linked lists in C++ found this thread, which uses bad C++ practices**. Note that I said *"Bad C++ practices"* not *"Bad C practices"*.

Comment: @Manu343726 thats clear BRO , next time i will pay more attention

Comment: to be fair, there are also some bad C practices here. casting return value of malloc, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `create_list` function:

```
LISTE_VALUE* create_list()
{   int i;
    LISTE_VALUE* first; // <<== Here
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        insertion(&first,i);

    }
    return(first);
}
```

You do not initialize the `first` pointer, but its value is later used in the `insertion` as the pointer of the next element of the final node of your list:

```
void insertion(LISTE_VALUE **first,int a)
{
    LISTE_VALUE *p;
    p=(LISTE_VALUE*)malloc(sizeof(LISTE_VALUE));
    p->d=a;
    p->next=*first; // <<== In the first call, *first is uninitialized
    *first=p;
}
```

Add `= NULL` to fix this problem:

```
LISTE_VALUE* create_list()
{   int i;
    LISTE_VALUE* first = NULL; // <<== Fix
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        insertion(&first,i);

    }
    return(first);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is invalid

```
LISTE_VALUE* create_list()
{   int i;
    LISTE_VALUE* first;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        insertion(&first,i);

    }
    return(first);
}
```

variable first was not initialized so it has any arbitrary value. 
You must write

```
    LISTE_VALUE* first = NULL;
```